# DateTime 2018 and 2019 week count PHP bug?

Tags: php, datetime

Wanted to get maximum weeks in a year, and thought this would be the simplest way to get this number, but I was surprised,that the last day in a year could be in the first week. Is this because these days are in the first half of the week?
So I know how to get the correct number, I'm just wondering about the logic.

```
<?php
echo (new DateTime('2016-12-31 00:00:00'))->format('W'); //52

echo (new DateTime('2017-12-31 00:00:00'))->format('W'); //52

echo (new DateTime('2018-12-31 00:00:00'))->format('W'); //01
echo (new DateTime('2018-12-30 00:00:00'))->format('W'); //52

echo (new DateTime('2019-12-31 00:00:00'))->format('W'); //01
echo (new DateTime('2019-12-30 00:00:00'))->format('W'); //01
echo (new DateTime('2019-12-29 00:00:00'))->format('W'); //52

echo (new DateTime('2020-12-31 00:00:00'))->format('W'); //53
```

Found by answered links (Wikipedia):

> **Last week**
>
> The last week of the ISO week-numbering year, i.e. the 52nd or 53rd
>   one, is the week before week 01. This week’s properties are:
>
> It has the year's last Thursday in it.
>
> It is the last week with a majority (4 or more) of its days in
>   December.
>
> Its middle day, Thursday, falls in the ending year.
>
> Its last day is the Sunday nearest to 31 December.
>
> It has 28 December in it. Hence the latest possible dates are 28
>   December through 3 January, the earliest 21 through 28 December.
>
> If 31 December is on a Monday, Tuesday or Wednesday, it is in week 01
>   of the next year. If it is on a Thursday, it is in week 53 of the year
>   just ending; if on a Friday it is in week 52 (or 53 if the year just
>   ending is a leap year); if on a Saturday or Sunday, it is in week 52
>   of the year just ending

Comment: The weeks are correct, for more information about week 53 see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably following [the ISO week date system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date). Citing that wikipedia article:

> The ISO 8601 definition for week 01 is the week with the year's first Thursday in it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the last week of the year you can use this simple function:

```
function getIsoWeeksInYear($year) {
  $date = new DateTime;
  $date->setISODate($year, 53);
  return ($date->format("W") === "53" ? 53 : 52);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was going to subtract day by day from the last day, or add week by week from the beginning of the year, and get the biggest number.